# ER diagram relationship

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, relationship, diagram

I have an entity 'Human' where there are attributes like ID (primary key), name, surname, age, sex, address etc. Then i have few other entities like sys admin, employee, manager, accountant. How do i show in an ER diagram than every one of those entities implement attributes from 'Human' entity by foreign key ID?

My solution was just to add relationship between 4 of those entities and human entity, but since relationship can only be two ways, on special occasions three ways maximum, it's not a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you need exactly to do? What I understood is that you want all of `Employee`, `Manager` and `Accountant` be related to `Human` table right?

Comment: Yes. And i want to show it on ER diagram.

Comment: You should use **generalization** for the jobs. And in an ER you don't show any fk. This happens later in the normalization and database creation.

Comment: Didn't quite understand your comment.

Comment: So how do i do it? how do i show this relationship on ER diagram ?

Comment: put the screen shot of datamodel or ER diagram you tried!

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/9ke7zwc0r/

Forgot to add cardinality but it's 1 to 1

Comment: So, anyone? Or am is it impossible to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy, Here is an example:

[image]
In this way you can design your db and link the entities with attributes.